# Send email automatic

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us

I would like to send an automatic email to the client when he sends a contact form, I am tempted like this:

```
    $mailTemplate->addBcc($post['email']);
    $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
        ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
        ->sendTransactional(
            Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
            Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
            array_keys($recipients),
            array_values($recipients),
            array('data' => $postObject)
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('contact_us');

//Getting the Store E-Mail Sender Name.
$senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

//Getting the Store General E-Mail.
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');

//Variables for Confirmation Mail.
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTemplateVariables['name'] = $customerName;
$emailTemplateVariables['email'] = $customerEmail;
$emailTemplateVariables['content'] = $content;

//Appending the Custom Variables to Template.
$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

//Sending E-Mail to Customers.
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
 ->setToName($senderName)
 ->setToEmail($customerEmail)
 ->setBody($processedTemplate)
 ->setSubject($subject)
 ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
 ->setFromName($senderName)
 ->setType('html');
 try{
     //Confimation E-Mail Send
     $mail->send();
 }
 catch(Exception $error)
 {
     Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($error->getMessage());
     return false;
 }
 ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll try to do it this way.

Comment: can you please modify your entire code?

Comment: Yes, I would like to send a copy to the client's email, the email he places at the time of sending the form.